# GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found using google apps endpoint engine backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I followed the tutorial below.

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0

which basically added a GAE backend to my existing app.  I then try out the example below, run it on the local development server and I get the exception below which occurs after

```
Note result = endpoint.insertNote(note).execute();
```

is called.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
```

My code is below.

```
package com.cloudnotes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.content.Context;
import com.cloudnotes.noteendpoint.Noteendpoint;
import com.cloudnotes.noteendpoint.model.Note;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      new EndpointsTask().execute(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
        protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

          Noteendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Noteendpoint.Builder(
              AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
              new JacksonFactory(),
              new HttpRequestInitializer() {
              public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
              });
      Noteendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
      endpointBuilder).build();
      try {
          Note note = new Note().setDescription("Note Description");
          String noteID = new Date().toString();
          note.setId(noteID);

          note.setEmailAddress("E-Mail Address");      
          Note result = endpoint.insertNote(note).execute();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
          return (long) 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your backend running? If you visit http://localhost:your_port/_ah/api/explorer do you see your APIs running?

Comment: @Jake , is the issue still on? The tutorial link you have provided is for web application, but your code is for android application?

Comment: Some additional instructions have been put in the sample.

Comment: @DanHolevoet no i can't see anything

Answer (score 5):

Another possible cause for this problem is not setting the correct applicationId in appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>APPLICATION_ID_HERE</application>
```

...

```
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: It's a shame this wasn't mentioned in the [official tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints)

Comment: where can i find application id

Answer (score 5):

Another possible reason for 404 if you call the method with a null parameter and the method does not accept null parameters.

I had a similar issue with a method with 4 String parameters and I sent null for one of them and all I got was a stupid 404.

Another possible reason for 404 on the development(local) server is that you have a parameter with some strange characters (like a url for example) that the development(local) server does not handle correctly event if it works fine on the app engine live servers. Possible solution: instead of multiple params use a simple java object.

Comment: This was indeed my fault. I now added @Nullable annotation. Thanks

Comment: This was also my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it.

**A little background**
I had two versions of the API deployed to App Engine which I believe it should be OK. The admin console didn't show any problem and I was getting the **200 OK** code after deploying version 2 of the API in log file.

```
/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs 200 118ms 8kb
```

but no matter what I tried I was always getting the **404 Not Found** error.

I am not sure what the problem was but I think Web Server at App Engine was redirecting all the requests to the version 1. It could be because both versions had the following settings in their web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Solution**
I removed version 1 and redeployed version 2. Then everything just worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

This comes down to the app engine default version being different from the one you've deployed. Go here:
https://appengine.google.com/deployment?app_id=s~your-project-id
and change your default version

Answer (score 0):

this happen because your deploy back-end is not fully deployed. just re-deploy your back-end and make sure you got the message deploy succeed. you can check the detail deploy process on the top page header. also, you can test by visiting the url to check:

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://[YOUR_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/_ah/api#p/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your plugin and dependency libraries to the latest version. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37639701/857346.

Answer (score 0):

In build gradle do:

```
 minifyEnabled false
```